# Change Environment Variables HOME in Windows to not have an semicolon

Tags: windows, variables, environment, cd

I have kind of an weird problem. I cant access my HOME directory in Git Bash or CMD using `cd ~`  or `cd`. I set the Enviroment Variable to `C/Users/274338` but it somehow registers as `C/Users/274338;`.
Also it was working before and i cant recall changing anything. How can i change that?

[using cd in git bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77GG7.png)
[Enviroment Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCxzj.png)

Using `cd ~`  i expected to go to my set Home directory. I tried changing the variable but to my knowledge it was correct. The directory is existing as can be seen in my image.

Answer (score 0):

modify `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\profile` and set $HOME variable to your `HOME`.

```
HOME="/c/Users/274338"
```

Save and open Git Bash and execute cd ~. You should be in `/C/Users/274338`

EDIT:
**To change the HOME environment variable in Windows**

- Click the Start button, type "environment properties" into the search bar
- In the System Properties window, click "Environment Variables."
- Under "User variables" or "System variables" (depending on whether you want to change the variable for the current user or all users), find the `HOME` variable.
- Click "Edit" to change the value of the `HOME` variable.
- Enter the new path for the `HOME` variable and click "OK" to save the changes.
- Click "OK" again to close the Environment Variables window

Comment: First of all thank you, that did help fix my problem for Git Bash atleast, but the problem still remains for cmd.

Comment: i think this will solve your issue with cmd